# How to select only first available checkbox with webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

i have list of checkboxes and I am selecting them one by one

```
List<WebElement> props = driver.findElementsByXPath("//input[@type='checkbox']");
        for (WebElement prop : props)
            if (!prop.isSelected()) {
                prop.click();
            }
```

But i need to select only the first available one.
How do I achieve this pls?

Comment: props.get(1).click();

Comment: Put a break inside the if condition of the for loop...

Comment: No, your **Business Requirement** / **Test Case** can't be `select only the first available one`. It should be a specific `checkbox` which needs to be selected. In that case you need to locate the intended `checkbox` through a locator `id`, `name`, `css` or `xpath` and call `click()` method on it. Inducing a `List` is absolutely unnecessary. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

if you want to select only first checkbox, why are you getting all the checkbox?

Following code will give you all the checkbox on the page.

```
List<WebElement> props = driver.findElementsByXPath("//input[@type='checkbox']");
```

To get only first checkbox, you can use the following code.  Xpath allow you to use subscript operator, just make a note that index starts with 1 and not 0.

```
WebElement firstCheckbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox'][1]"))
```

Comment: I need to select first available check box. The very firs one could be eg. already selected or greyed out etc...

Answer (score 0):

List props = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));

int size= props.size();

for(int i=1;i<=size;i++){

WebElement element = driver.findElementsByXPath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])["+i+"]");

if(!(element.isSelected()){

```
element.click();
i = size+1;
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved it with break and works well

```
List<WebElement> props = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
    for (WebElement prop : props)
        if (!prop.isSelected()) {
            prop.click()
            break;
        }
```